# Loading image in python using urllib.request

Tags: python

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQiLweAoxgQ&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_&index=22) and getting stuck with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PycharmProjects/YouTube/Beer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 44
    `Parse list of key=value strings where keys are not duplicated.`
```

I am new to programming and to Python anyone have an idea what the issue is? Please be nice its my first time asking on Stack!

```
import random
import urllib.request
def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
download_web_image(`https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/8547538?s=460&u=8a4be84ff4870a332fe94c11fca02b432fb9f83e&v=4`)
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRUdS.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you are new then maybe you have not heard of the python package called requests.  It is going to be much easier to use than urllib.  From your code above, however it looks like your url is not properly formatted using quotes, I think you have back ticks.  " not `

Comment: Is that the entire error message? The line beginning with `download_web_image(` seems to be somewhat broken, can you clarify what the code actually looks like?

Comment: added picture above

Comment: @JeffTilton What import do you recommend to get image.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import urllib.request
def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
download_web_image("https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/8547538?s=460&u=8a4be84ff4870a332fe94c11fca02b432fb9f83e&v=4")
```

Comment: It has something to to with the request . Maybe i didnt import it correcttey? import urllib.request